# Time taken by virus to reach all nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

Given a connected graph, with weighted edges, a virus starts from a given node. It takes x seconds for the virus to travel from a node to one of its neighbours where x is directly proportional to the weight of the edge.

If you are allowed to remove one edge from this graph in order to maximize the ammount of time it takes for the virus to infect all the nodes. How to find this edge?

I could come up with an $O(E\cdot(V+E))$ solution to remove every edge one by one and then run BFS to find out the time it takes for the virus to infect every node. Is there a better solution in terms of time complexity?

This challenge was asked in one of the codenation interviews. It is mentioned in this interview experience: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/codenation-interview-experience-full-time-sde-off-campus/

Comment: There are potentially $O(n^2)$ edges, so removing each edge in turn and then running BFS is going to take $O(n^3)$ time. But you need only consider the $O(n)$ edges in the shortest path tree found by Dijkstra, which indeed gives you an $O(n^2)$-time algorithm.

Comment: @j_random_hacker If I understand correctly, considering there could be $n^2$ edges, my algorithm was $O(n^2(n^2))$ as I would run BFS $n^2$ times and each BFS will take $(n + n^2)$ time. What you suggested would be $O(n(n^2))$ as the number of edges to try removing would decrease but I would still have to run BFS on the original graph.

Comment: Is removing an edge that causes the graph to become disconnected allowed?? Because if the graph is disconnected then it takes infinite time for the virus to infect all nodes

Comment: @droptop yes, that is allowed. It can be handled as a trivial case.

Comment: @AyushGoel if it is allowed the I don't see how it's a trivial case. Just find a bridge in the graph with dfs starting from an arbitrary node and pluck it

Comment: Plus  If you intend to maximize infection time without letting it become infinite then you only have to consider removing non-bridge edges

Comment: @droptop you should probably just assume the graph is 2-connected; as Ayush Goel says, it really is a trivial case.

Comment: @AyushGoel: You are right, my analysis was missing a factor of $n$. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: BTW I suspect that some kind of "enhanced Dijkstra's algorithm" that keeps more information about each vertex (e.g., the lengths of the shortest *two* paths from the source to each vertex) is the way to go here, but I don't have time right now to think about this in more detail.